# One sine-wave vector with different frequencies

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a vector with many frequencies. Now I try to program a sine-wave, which generates for each frequency one period and put it into one vector... (similar like a sweep signal)

Finally I want to plot this...

I already tried this, but it doesn't work correctly..

```
%fr = Frequency-Vector with 784 Elements from 2.0118e+04 to 1.9883e+04 Hz

fs = 48000; %Sampling frequency [Hz]

tstart = 0;
tstep = 1/fs;
tend = (length(fr))*(1/min(fr))-tstep;
t3 = tstart3:tstep3:tend3;



sin3 = [];
for i = 1:length(fr)/2
sin3 = [sin3 sin(2*pi*fr(i)*t3)];
end

tstart4 = 0;
tstep4 = 1/fs2;
tend4 = tstep4*length(sin3);
t4 = tstart4:tstep4:tend4-tstep4;

figure;
plot(t4,sin3)
```

Could you please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking to make something like this:http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/chirp.html

Comment: if you define fs2, fr, and edit the line including t3=..., the code works, what are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: Thank you, but I have only forgot this here to change :) The problem was the time, which was necessary to calculate this.. but radarhead's suggestion with cumsum is perfect :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If reversed engineer your codes correctly, it seems like you wanted to generate a chirp frequency. It could be more efficient if you do it as follows

```
fr = linspace(2.0118e4, 1.9883e4, 784);  % Frequency content
%fr = linspace(2e4, 1e4, 784);           % Try this for a wider chirp

fs = 48e3;
phi = cumsum(2*pi*fr/fs);
s1 = sin(phi);

spectrogram(s1, 128, 120, 128, fs);      % View the signal in time vs frequency
```